# Unable to assign null to int? when using ternary (?:) operator

Tags: c#, nullable, conditional-operator

Can anyone help me understand why the following doesnt compile?

```
string intAsString = "123";
int? nullableInt = null;

nullableInt = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(intAsString) 
    ? Convert.ToInt32(intAsString) 
    : null;
```

As it complains that:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `int` and `null`

I expected that since `int?` can be assigned `null`, this statement should work fine. It's easy enough to work around, but I'd like to understand why my expectation was wrong.

Comment: If you take a look at the [?: operator documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), it states that *"The type of `consequent` and `alternative` must be the same, or there must be an implicit conversion from one type to the other."*. In the case above, the `int` type is different than the `null` type, and there is no implicit conversion between them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly cast the `Int32` you get from `Convert.ToInt32`:

```cs
string intAsString = "123";
int? nullableInt = null;

nullableInt = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(intAsString) ? (int?)(Convert.ToInt32(intAsString)) : null;
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates -- vote to close them as a duplicate instead

Comment: Thanks! As I mentioned in my post, there's plenty of easy ways to work around this, but I was curious as to why a workaround is needed. Looks like this was a duplicate post anyway (which I expected), and the answer on the original explains why this workaround is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler finds out you have "int", and "null" as your result type. It is not smart enough to find a type fitting both. Cast one or the other explicitly to `int?`